# How to extract fields from encoded JSON object

Tags: json, jq

Hi i'm trying to extract the tokens `last_name`, `first_name` and `phone` from the following JSON data:

```
{"message":"{\"_\":\"user\",\"pFlags\":{\"contact\":true},\"flags\":2167,\"id\":95384129,\"access_hash\":\"780828213343231334\",\"first_name\":\"xaa\",\"last_name\":\"xz\",\"phone\":\"989123930793\",\"photo\":{\"_\":\"userProfilePhoto\",\"photo_id\":\"409671715068685579\",\"photo_small\":{\"_\":\"fileLocation\",\"dc_id\":4,\"volume_id\":\"455930331\",\"local_id\":281464,\"secret\":\"3283911659027961987\"},\"photo_big\":{\"_\":\"fileLocation\",\"dc_id\":4,\"volume_id\":\"455930331\",\"local_id\":281466,\"secret\":\"3533047346646019161\"}},\"status\":{\"_\":\"userStatusLastMonth\"}}","phone":"989123930793","@version":"1","typ":"tg_contacts","access_hash":"780828213343231334","id":95384129,"@timestamp":"2020-01-26T13:53:31.091Z","path":"/home/user/mirror2/users_5d3de570e549953b6163eb0f.log","type":"redis","flags":2167,"host":"ubuntu","imported_from":"tg"}
```

This my command

```
jq -r '[.first_name, .last_name, .phone]|@csv'
```

How ever I can extract only the `phone` field and I don't know why I can't extract `first_name` and `last_name`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try

```
jq -r '.' file.json
```

you will see that there are no first and last name, only phone.

```json
{
  "message": "{\"_\":\"user\",\"pFlags\":{\"contact\":true},\"flags\":2167,\"id\":95384129,\"access_hash\":\"780828213343231334\",\"first_name\":\"xaa\",\"last_name\":\"xz\",\"phone\":\"989123930793\",\"photo\":{\"_\":\"userProfilePhoto\",\"photo_id\":\"409671715068685579\",\"photo_small\":{\"_\":\"fileLocation\",\"dc_id\":4,\"volume_id\":\"455930331\",\"local_id\":281464,\"secret\":\"3283911659027961987\"},\"photo_big\":{\"_\":\"fileLocation\",\"dc_id\":4,\"volume_id\":\"455930331\",\"local_id\":281466,\"secret\":\"3533047346646019161\"}},\"status\":{\"_\":\"userStatusLastMonth\"}}",
  "phone": "989123930793",
  "@version": "1",
  "typ": "tg_contacts",
  "access_hash": "780828213343231334",
  "id": 95384129,
  "@timestamp": "2020-01-26T13:53:31.091Z",
  "path": "/home/user/mirror2/users_5d3de570e549953b6163eb0f.log",
  "type": "redis",
  "flags": 2167,
  "host": "ubuntu",
  "imported_from": "tg"
}
```

The fields you are looking for, are into the `.message`, which is a string, an **encoded JSON object**.

`jq` has the [`fromjson`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Convertto/fromJSON) builtin that you can use and get it as a JSON:

```bsh
jq -r '.message | fromjson | [.first_name, .last_name, .phone]|@csv' file.json
"xaa","xz","989123930793"
```